# Is a = 0 a valid counterexample to this statement?

Tags: ring-theory

This is an exercise in a text I am reading for a ring theory course.

Suppose the ring R contains element a such that 1) a is idempotent and 2) a is not a zero divisor of R.  Deduce that a serves as a multiplicative identity for R.

What if a = 0.  0 is idempotent.  0 is not a zero divisor.  0 does not serve as a multiplicative identity in a ring (except in the ring {0}).

This exercise is not homework but is a suggested practice problem by the prof, so I would most appreciate a subtle hint if possible.

Comment: $0\cdot x=0$ for any $x\in R$ so $0$ is definitely a zero divisor

Comment: @marwalix Well, some authors define zero divisors to be nonzero. It just depends. Clearly some flexibility is required for terms like this one :)

Comment: You're right if we do not allow for $0$ to be a zero divisor then we should rephrase the theorem: if $a$ is idempotent and a non zero divisor of zero then:-)

Comment: For what its worth, I double checked the definition of zero divisor (given in the same text) and it explicitly states that 0 is NOT a zero divisor.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Sounds like an error then :) Still, you can fruitfully solve the modified problem.

Comment: If element a in ring R does not equal 0, and a is NOT a zero divisor, and a is idempotent then a serves as the multiplicative identitiy.  Proof: Let x be an arbitrary element in R. a(ax - x) = aax - ax = ax - ax = 0. So ax -x =0. So ax =x.  Also (xa - x)a = xaa - xa = xa - xa = 0.  So xa =x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If zero is considered to be a correct counterexample for this problem, then the problem is not a very good one, having a trivial answer for a pedantic reason. We can surmise this was not the intended effect, and that the author meant for something meaningful to happen.

In all likelihood, the author probably meant for zero to count as a zero divisor. This is both allowed and prohibited depending on the text. But from context, it seems like you should assume the former.

If $e$ is the idempotent, the key is to multiply $ex-x$ and $xe-x$ with $e$ in a couple ways and note the results, considering that $e$ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: OK thanks.  This explains my befuddlement over a similar claim in the Wikipedia article "Zero Divisor" :  An  idempotent element e not equal to 1 of a ring is always a two-sided zero divisor, since e(1-e)=0=(1-e)e.  Here they must be assuming that e is not 0, (which is consistent with their definition).  Right?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer I don't see that the distinction is important here. Maybe you could just rephrase it as "if e is an idempotent and e is not 1 and not 0, then e is a zero divisor." That much is certainly true.

Comment: they must be assuming that 0 IS a zero divisor.